# Broken string ending when converting SecureString to UTF8

Tags: .net, powershell

I'm currently working on a PowerShell function which turns `SecureString` into a Base64 data. The encoding should be done out of UTF8 encoded data, so I had to implement a couple of preliminary steps in order to get it right and here is what I currently have:

```sh
function ToBase64String {
    Param([Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()][Security.SecureString]$string)
    $srcBufferPtr = [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::SecureStringToCoTaskMemUnicode($string)
    $dstBuffer = [System.Byte[]]::CreateInstance([System.Byte], [System.Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetMaxByteCount($string.Length))
    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::Copy($srcBufferPtr, $dstBuffer, 0, $dstBuffer.Length)
    $utf8Bytes = [System.Text.Encoding]::Convert([System.Text.Encoding]::Unicode, [System.Text.Encoding]::GetEncoding(28591), $dstBuffer)
    $base64Str = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String($utf8Bytes)
    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::ZeroFreeCoTaskMemUnicode($srcBufferPtr)
    Write-Output $base64Str
}
```

For some reason, however, some ending bytes don't match the reference data. Not sure what exactly i'm doing wrong here:

```sh
$utf8String = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetString([System.Text.Encoding]::Default.GetBytes("test"))
$utf8Bytes = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($utf8String)
$secureString = $(ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force -String "test")

# Reference value "dGVzdA=="
$utf8Base64 = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String($utf8Bytes) 
# Function value "dGVzdAA="
$secureBase64 = $(ToBase64String $secureString)
```

Comment: You second example has a `NUL` character encoded at the end of the string. Check where you get it as an extra in your function.

Comment: Whats your use case? Why not store the encoded string with `ConvertFrom-SecureString`?

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon I need a Base64 string out of UTF8 bytes, while `ConvertFrom-SecureString` makes a UTF16 out of secure string. I understand that I can convert the UTF16 string into UTF8 and later into Base64, but this step looks just irrelevant to me for my goal

Comment: @PawełŁukasik you are right here. By playing around with it I found that `[System.Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetMaxByteCount($string.Length)` is 2 bytes longer than it's required for the UTF-8 bytes buffer. I believe you can turn your comment into an answer if you can explain why it works this way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- As you've discovered, the [`.GetMaxByteCount()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.encoding.getmaxbytecount) method was the wrong one to use, as it reports the *maximum* number of byte required to encode a given number of .NET `[char]` (`[uint16]` Unicode code units) for a given encoding, not the *actual* number for a *given string*.
- Your `ToBase64String` function can be greatly simplified, which also bypasses your problem - see below.
- **Caveat**:

  - You're using the Base64-encoding of a *plain-text password*, which negates the - [limited](https://github.com/dotnet/platform-compat/blob/master/docs/DE0001.md) - benefits that [`[securestring]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Security.SecureString) instances can provide.

```bash
# !! This is INSECURE, because the Base64 encoding is based on the
# !! *plain-text* version of the password.
function ToBase64String {
  Param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory)]
    [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
    [securestring] $string
  )
  [Convert]::ToBase64String(
    [Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes(
      [pscredential]::new('dummy', $string).GetNetworkCredential().Password
    )
  )
}
```